# Ionic4: searchbar results not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

I am using [ion-searchbar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar) in my app. I use the searchbar to filter a list of customers by first name and/or last name, but I am really struggling with these two issues:

**Issue 1:** The search bar only matches first name OR last name, but not both at the same time. For example: If I am a customer and my name is Marshall Legend and I type in `Marshall` the filter will work OR if I type in `Legend` the filter will work, but if i type in `Marshall Legend` I get no matches.

**Issue 2:** This is easier to explain as a scenario. The customers list is correctly filtering the list and showing the correct results, such as only people named "Marshall" are showing when I've typed "Marshall" into the searchbar. However, then a new customer is added to the list (from another client) and all of a sudden all customers are being displayed and the filter is ignored, even though "Marshall" is still in my searchbar.

I've been struggling with these two issues for an embarrassing amount of time and would greatly appreciate any help. Below is my code:

**My component code**

```
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {
  public searchTerm: string = "";
  public customerCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  public customers: any[];
  public unfilteredCustomers: any[];

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, 
    public modalController: ModalController,
    private databaseService: DatabaseService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.customerCollection = this.afs.collection('Customers');
    this.customerCollection.valueChanges().subscribe( val => {
      this.customers = val;
      this.unfilteredCustomers = val;
    });
  }

  /**
   * Search functionality 
   */
  public onSearchTerm() {
    if(/\S/.test(this.searchTerm)){
      this.customers = this.unfilteredCustomers.filter(customer => {
        return customer.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())  
        || customer.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase());
      });
    } else {
      this.customers = this.unfilteredCustomers;
    }
  }
```

**My template code**

```
    <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let customer of customers">
          <ion-item-options side="start">
            <ion-item-option (click)="viewCustomerDetails(customer)">Details</ion-item-option>
          </ion-item-options>
        <ion-item>
         <ion-label>
         <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon> {{customer?.firstName}} 
           {{customer?.lastName}}
         </ion-label>
         </ion-item>
          <ion-item-options side="end">
            <ion-item-option color="danger" (click)="removeCustomer(customer)">Return</ion-item-option>
          </ion-item-options>
    </ion-item-sliding>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem 1**

Your search logic is as follows:

1. If first name *or* last name equals "legend", return true
2. If first name *or* last name equals "marshall", return true
3. If first name *or* last name equals "marshall legend", return true

Since the first name and last names are split up between two properties in Firestore, the  third scenario will never happen.  Try this instead:

```
  public onSearchTerm() {
    if (searchTerms.length < 1) {
      this.customers = this.unfilteredCustomers;
      return;
    }

    const searchTerms = this.searchTerm.split(' ').map(s => s.trim().toLowerCase());

    this.customers = this.unfilteredCustomers.filter(customer => {
      var firstName = customer.firstName.toLowerCase();
      var lastName = customer.lastName.toLowerCase();

      var results = searchTerms.filter(name => firstName.includes(name) || lastName.includes(name));

      return results.length > 0;
    });

  }
```

**Problem 2**

In your ngOnInit function you're subscribed to your customers collection watching for any changes, and when that happens it overwrites your this.customers variable.  That's why your list refreshes showing all results. Try this instead:

```
  ngOnInit(){
    this.customerCollection = this.afs.collection('Customers');
    this.customerCollection.valueChanges().subscribe( val => {
      this.unfilteredCustomers = val;

      // If there is a search term, filter the results
      if (this.searchTerm.trim().length > 0) {
        this.onSearchTerm();
      } else {
        this.customers = val;   
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works partially. It did solve issue 1, but only partially issue 2. Now if I search at `Joe Smith` it will find Joe Smith, but if there is also a `Sam Smith` ( or anyone matching smith) in the list that will be displayed as well. Again I appreciate your time and response!

Comment: You're going to have to change the logic to first filter for an exact match, and if no results are found, do the broader search above.

Answer (score -1):

You can use like this

```
public onSearchTerm() {
if(/\S/.test(this.searchTerm)){
  this.customers = this.unfilteredCustomers.filter(customer => {
    let fullname = customer.firstName+" "+customer.lastName
    return fullname.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())  ;
  });
} else {
  this.customers = this.unfilteredCustomers;
}
```

}

This will return either matching firstname or lastname not both

```
return customer.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())  
    || customer.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase());
```